# Azure error:Retry policy did not allow for a retry,where is wrong?

Tags: python, azure

**I use this code to call azure api:**
http://pythonfiddle.com/sjj/

**But the error message is:**

```
    Client-Request-ID=b68d2b74-5e54-11e8-9b68-b025aa1fef84 Retry policy did not allow for a retry: , HTTP status code=Unknown, Exception=HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dapsjj.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /container1/top_201819.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024832F0C668>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I don not know where is wrong,can you tell me?

Comment: `dapsjj.blob.core.windows.net` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sraw  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[Errno 11001] getaddrinfofailed means the hostname you're passing to run can't be resolved.

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 8080)
```

If it still not working. You can try '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' in case that's the problem.

Comment: I modified my code as you said,but the mistake still exists.

Comment: Check your DNS-settings
Check your firewall settings (connections on remote 53 port /TCP|UDP/ must be enabled, better - globally)
You can get more detailed report, if you'll clone from console with -v --debug options

Comment: My computer is win10 pro.I opened my computer's 53 port. When I use 'telnet 127.0.0.1 53',it said "Could not connect to the host 127.0.0.1. Port 53: connection failed".

Comment: If you are using proxy then you need to add http_proxy environment variable if not then remove the same from the environment variable, see if it works for you.